# Get array key first value without knowing the key index

Tags: php, arrays

```
   $responseData = json_decode($response);
print_r($responseData->errors);
```

How do I get the first key and [0] item, even if i dont know what is the first key value? sometime like this? I want to get the text "The first name field is required."

```
print_r($responseData->errors[0][0]);


stdClass Object
(
    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => The first name field is required.
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => The last name field is required.
        )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi you can try with **array_keys** to get an array of all keys here is an example code from PHP.net

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));

$array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
print_r(array_keys($array, "blue"));

$array = array("color" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
               "size"  => array("small", "medium", "large"));
print_r(array_keys($array));
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => color
    [1] => size
)
```

To get only the first key you can use **array_key_first**
example code

```
<?php
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 
$firstKey = array_key_first($array);
var_dump($firstKey);
?>
```

Output

```
Above code will output a string 'a'
```

for more details please visit 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
var_dump(current($array));
var_dump(key($array));
```

Note if your array internal pointer is not point to the first element, you can reset it with `reset($array);` first.

Answer (score 0):

PHP have the function can help you [array_key_first](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php):

print_r($responseData->errors[array_key_first($responseData->errors)][0]);

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFirstVal($errors) {
    foreach($errors as $key => $error) { 
        return $error[0];
    }
}
```

You may use

```
foreach($errors as $error) {
    #code ...
}
```

if you don't need the key name.

Answer (score 0):

my data for a test

```
$respErrors = (object)[
  'first_name' => ['The first name field is required.'],
  'last_name' => ['The last name field is required.'],
];
```

If only the first error text is needed you can just do this

```
$firstField = reset($respErrors)[0];
```

The Info from last field

```
$lastField = end($respErrors)[0];
```

If you need keys and values, you can also use foreach

```
foreach($respErrors as $key => $value){
  echo "key: ".$key." value[0]: ".$value[0]."<br>\n";
  break;
}
```

To get all values, remove the line with break.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$json =<<<JSON
[
    {
        "first_name": [
            "The first name field is required."
        ]
    },
    {
        "last_name": [
            "The last name field is required."
        ]
    }
]
JSON;

$response = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($response as $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $array) {
        printf("Key: '%s', First error message: '%s'\n", $key, $array[0]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Key: 'first_name', First error message: 'The first name field is required.'
Key: 'last_name', First error message: 'The last name field is required.'
```

Given your response, it may be easier to work with one less layer:

```
$keyed_messages = array_merge(...$response);
var_export($keyed_messages);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'first_name' => 
    array (
      0 => 'The first name field is required.',
    ),
    'last_name' => 
    array (
      0 => 'The last name field is required.',
    ),
  )
```

Then to loop through something like the first_name messages you can just do:

```
 foreach($keyed_messages['first_name'] as $message) {
     // Something.
 }
```